# Show duplicate header in the VTC preview

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

Currently, when I try to close a post as a dupe of another post which is a dupe, I get:

[image]

Obviously, I'd like to find the original dupe link. For that, I need to open in a new tab, and then get it:

[image]
[image]

Could the dupe banner be shown in the VTC duplicate question preview itself?

Comment: Yes please.  This is very annoying.  Maybe if you close a question as a dupe of a dupe question the second dupe should just re-direct to the master question.  I think this already kind of happens for users that aren't logged in..

Comment: Any progress on this?